# .htaccess rewrite rule fail,dont know why

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I've such a rule in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([A-Z])([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/$ http://www\.google\.com
```

when I browser url "http://127.0.0.1:8008/BeiJing/FangChan/",the browser doestnt take me to google.com,but show me a 404 err page instead. dont know why.

Answer (score 0):

Use this one instead, because your `(.*)/` breaks it

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Z])([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/$ http://www\.google\.com
```

Comment: It works,but I thingk ^([A-Z])([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/$ and http://127.0.0.1:8008/BeiJing/FangChan/ dont match

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$
```

That'll match two levels deep, with or without a trailing slash. If you need to go deeper, you can just repeat the pattern, ending with a "/?".

Comment: I need to match the url as a whole

Comment: You mean you need to also match the domain? I'm not exactly sure that's possible. And if you need to match additional depths, that could be tricky, too, unless you're alright with using independent rules.